# Using material icon as comboImage constant

Tags: codenameone

am trying to change material icon as comboImage with the below code but it's not working:

```
 Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
 h.put("comboImage", FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_DROP_DOWN, "TitleCommand", 2F));
 UIManager.getInstance().addThemeProps(h);
 Display.getInstance().getCurrent().refreshTheme();
```

How can I change theme constant in code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use the existing theme hashtable in the init() method this approach should work. Once the constant is set it isn't refreshed like the rest of the theme. The approach by @diamond is the right one if you want to change this in runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
((DefaultLookAndFeel) UIManager.getInstance().getLookAndFeel()).setComboBoxImage(FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_ARROW_DROP_DOWN, "TitleCommand", 2F));
```

Comment: Thanks Diamond. It worked but DefaultLookAndFeel class is deprecated, is there any alternative?

Comment: Not that I know of, but like Shai mentioned in a comment above, your approach could work but if used properly in the `init()` method before the first initialization of your theme. DefaultLookAndFeel is deprecated but not gonna be removed.